# ValueType as property in class

Tags: c#, getter, value-type, reference-type

I am a bit confused with a concept of value types as properties in a class.
As far as I understand, when getter is called - a copy of value type is returned.
Let's have an example:

```cs
public struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public void Set(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Int32 X { get; set; }

    public void SetX(int x) => X = x;

    public Point Point { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new Test();
    test.SetX(10);
    test.Point.Set(20, 30);

    Console.WriteLine(test.X);
    Console.WriteLine($"{test.Point.X} {test.Point.Y}");
}
```

Point is not modified, since it is a value type, and getter gives us a copy, which makes sense. The thing I don't understand - why in this case X is modified? It is a value type also. This looks like a contradiction to me.
Please help me to understand what I am missing

Comment: In the Point case, you're making a change *to the value returned*. In the SetX case you're making a change *to the object containing X*. They're very different scenarios. If you had a `Test.SetPoint` method (e.g. `public void SetPoint(Point point) => Point = point;` then you'll see that method change the value too...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, but X in the object is a property with type int, doesn't that mean that when we type "object.X" - it returns a copy of X? I read your articles on value and ref types, and I understand it in a case of passing them as parameters to methods, though I am still confused when value type is a part of ref type, and it is used as a property

Comment: Yes, it returns a copy of the current value of X. But `SetX` changes that to a different value, just as if you set `test.X = 50;`.

Comment: I guess this is the reason you shouldn't use mutable structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Point is not modified, since it is a value type, and getter gives us a copy, which makes sense

Yes, because you get a make changes to local copy of `Point` returned by auto-property **getter**.

> The thing I don't understand - why in this case X is modified?

Because you are modifying object containing `X` not the copy of `X`. `X = x` invokes **setter** (there is no "returns copy" happening here) for auto-property which will write corresponding value to corresponding memory location.

Code for `Point` simulating this behavior can look for example like:

```cs
public void SetPoint(int x, int y) => Point = new Point{X= x, Y =y};
```

And in both cases the following will work:

```
test.X = 42;
test.Point = new Point {X = 7, Y = 42}
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ6BuBDMACYAUwGdg8BePKQgdzwBUTgAKASgG50jSA6AZULAAGsyQAGDlyb9BABQD2ASygsEYgDR4AzBM5o4SAJzNuwHkMn6jzACQAiAN6meC5WaEBfPE+muVPAE0PO0t0OC08UkgAYzI/YHQHdDwUvHC8NzwhPVS0iMyAvWTU9LgAFjwBFkyAD01MgE9WYpSktFzcoQo8GpyOlIDuhr6Uj3QxjH0IxAYmRJa8vABJFS0ELO88AHNBdkjdvAmF0oqqkVrWCgA+Dcpehf6U4+nTuSUVZlr6lTwm8hv4hRqHR4g4hHdNINyA0PEV2iUIoDAQ5tgdiAcJh4gA==)

Comment: to clarify: "test.Point.SomeMethod" - creates a copy of Point, whereas "test.Point = ..." - does not create, right?

Comment: In the first case you are reading the Point value (=make a copy), to access that SomeMethod. In the second case you are assigning a new value to the Point property of test

Comment: Arguably mutable structs are a bad idea anyway

Comment: @Hans Kesting, thank you, your comment seems "switched" me

Comment: @jonbee _"to clarify: `test.Point.SomeMethod` - creates a copy of `Point`"_ -  yes, because in this case `test.Point` represents read access (property getter), so this results in copying and then you invoke a method on the read data(copy), while in `test.Point = new Point...` there is write happening to the `Point` property.

Comment: Also see [Why are mutable structs “evil”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil). As Charlieface correctly pointed - mutable structs are quite often are questionable choice.

Answer (score 0):

To modify 'Test.Point' code this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test();
            test.SetX(10); // you assign a new value to the property
            // test.Point.Set(20, 30); - you change a copy of the value without assignment of the result to the property  
            test.Point = new Point(){ X = 20, Y = 30 }

            Console.WriteLine(test.X);
            Console.WriteLine($"{test.Point.X} {test.Point.Y}");
        }
```

*Among ValueTypes the struct only can have (user defined) properties or methods which can modify itself. It confuses a lot. You can follow recommendation to use the read-only structs to avoid any possibility of such behavior which is hard to identify.*

Comment: `Set` has return type of `void`, this will not even compile.

Comment: Sure. Was not too attentive.